# Flash audio mp3 player with javascript api wanted for playing online radios

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, audio

I am working on HTML5 website, and i need a player for playing online radio streams. I need to play mp3 streams - and i found that mp3 is not supported by mozilla.

So, i decided to use a flash component, that will play mp3 audio with javascript api (to control stream url, play/stop and volume), to make it work on all browsers... perhaps somebody can advice such plugin?

P.S. i have markup for player. Just need api.

Thanks everybody. I stopped on soundManager2. It is fantastic :)

Comment: Why not use something that provides all the fallbacks out of the box? Like http://www.jplayer.org/

Comment: I am not sure if it is fully customizable. Is it? I've seen that it provides ability just to specify css classes, but not to create any markup that you want.

I will write jquery plugin anyway - because player UI is quite huge, and custom.. so i need just a player.. will try jPlayer.. thanks.

Comment: I found http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/ - it can be used without UI, with just API.. i think it is more suitable.

Comment: Also very tiny player: http://www.varal.org/media/niftyplayer/

Comment: Those look nice as well. jPlayer *is* fully customizable bit it's big and complex.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox don't have builtin support for MP3 but can now use the OS to play MP3 on some systems : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Should work on : Windows Vista and newer, Android, Firefox OS.

Demo : http://netkoder.dk/netkoder/lyd_streaming.php